# Value of type 'GMSPlace' has no member 'viewport' in GooglePlaces Cocoapod 3.3.7

Tags: cocoapods, viewport, google-places, gmsplace

After a few years the problem described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790121/gmsplace-viewport-member-missing-in-googlemaps-cocoapod) reappears,

in the latest versions of GooglePlaces cocoapod (3.3.7) the **viewport** field is not accessible although the field is present in the class interface

```
//
//  GMSPlace.h
//  Google Places SDK for iOS
//
//  Copyright 2016 Google Inc.
//
//  Usage of this SDK is subject to the Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of
//  Service: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms
//

.....
other fields
.....

/**
* The recommended viewport for this place. May be nil if the size of the place is not known.
*
* This returns a viewport of a size that is suitable for displaying this place. For example,    a
* |GMSPlace| object representing a store may have a relatively small viewport, while a |GMSPlace|
* object representing a country may have a very large viewport.
*/
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly, nullable) GMSCoordinateBounds *viewport;

.....
.....
```

The update is required to ensure compatibility with the API and the field is very important for the app's business logic, what can I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you import both **GooglePlaces** and **GoogleMapsBase**.

GMSCoordinateBounds is defined in GoogleMapBase.

Google mentions this change in the version 3.5.0 changelog: https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/releases

> GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h no longer transitively includes classes from GoogleMapsBase.h, so if you use the GMSCoordinateBounds class in your code, you must now #import GoogleMapsBase/GoogleMapsBase.h as well.